# When I'm gathering digits while playing a message, I don't want the action URL to trigger if the caller hangs up

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I've got an inbound call endpoint that produces the following TwiML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="https://example.com/calling/twiml/add-to-queue" numDigits="1" actionOnEmptyResult="true">
    <Play>https://example-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ivr.wav</Play>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

This works fine when the caller answers and enters a digit (in that the action gets triggered correctly). I also want the behaviour of `actionOnEmptyResult`, because I want the caller to be put in the queue regardless if they don't press anything.

My problem therefore occurs when a caller hangs up during the Gather phase. Twilio still calls the action because `actionOnEmptyResult` is set to true, and my app will then try to add the caller into the queue, even though they've hung up. Basically, my current implementation results in a race condition as it attempts to 'add caller to queue' and 'call ended' at the same time.

I'd like it if there was a `actionOnHangUp`, although I appreciate that may be difficult to implement. How can I achieve this behaviour?

A hacky solution I can think of is - when the action endpoint gets called, if the `digits` parameter has a null value, wait 3 seconds and check if the call is still in progress before adding it to the queue. This would likely get around the race condition. However, it just doesn't feel like a nice solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, that I haven't tested, is to have your endpoint (https://example.com/calling/twiml/add-to-queue) check the [CallStatus attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters). If there is really a race condition when someone hangs up, have your add-to-queue method check the [CallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters). If the CallStatus is "completed" then do not add-to-queue.

Next, [this example from the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-redirect-after-gather&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x) shows how to continue a call if no digits are provided but you want to continue (and not hang-up). I modified to use your Twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<Response>
    <Gather action="https://example.com/calling/twiml/add-to-queue" numDigits="1">
       <Play>https://example-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ivr.wav</Play>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">
        https://example.com/calling/twiml/add-to-queue?Digits=TIMEOUT
    </Redirect>
</Response>
```

Comment: ahh yes that `digits=TIMEOUT` method would work actually, not sure why I didn't think of that :)

Comment: I got round to trying this method and it doesn't work. When the caller hangs up during the `gather` it still performs the redirect and sets the `digits` parameter to be `timeout`. Therefore the code adds the caller to the call queue, even though they've hung up.
With regards to your first solution, I attempted that. It also didn't work; I retrieve the call just before adding it to the queue, and the status is `in-progress`, even though the caller has hung up. 
I've had to change the way it works to just loop the IVR message a few times before ending the call unfortunately

Comment: Another suggestion is to add a small delay, like 1 or 2 seconds before checking the status of the "in-progress" call. Telecom is not instantaneous. Twilio will correctly update the status to "completed" after the caller hangs-up. Your app might be checking with milisecconds of tolerance while a few seconds is what is needed. And if that doesn't work you'll need to rearchitect what you are trying to accomplish - for example,  either responding to a "completed" webhook or having your queueing app check for an appropriate call status before dequeing.

Comment: yeah know what you mean. For the time being the client is happy to loop the IVR message a few times and wait for a key before queuing. 
The delay does make sense though, I’ll have a play with that.
It’s just a little annoying there’s no way to distinguish between timing out and hanging up out of the box

Comment: To me that kind of renders their actionOnEmptyResult as pointless (because you can achieve the same functionality with the Redirect verb).  Would love to hear an official response on this, any idea where the best place to ask would be (other than their customer support which I’ve had little luck with in the past)?

Comment: I get what you are saying however a phone based application is going to need to be resilient enough to deal with hang-ups at inopportune times. Hanging up during state transitions is a fairly likely occurrence. Twilio will accurately keep track of both timing out from Gather and hanging-up. That is what the webhooks are used for. "add-to-queue" will need to distinguish between no digits, digits, and a hang-up.

Comment: `That is what the webhooks are used for. "add-to-queue" will need to distinguish between no digits, digits, and a hang-up.`
Yeah I totally agree, all I'm saying is that this doesn't seem to be possible. If you try setting it up you'll see what I mean. Create a webhook that handles the `add-to-queue` call, and query the call status in there (even after a delay). Send a `Gather` to it, call the number, and hang up during the message. From what I'm seeing, the result back from querying the call status is returning "In progress" as opposed to "Completed"

Comment: I have not had Twilio return a response of "in-progress" for a call that was actually disconnected. Especially after receiving a webhook that said the call was "completed" or any other terminal status. It does make sense to me that the Gather endpoint is receiving a webhook of "in-progress" as the disconnect state change is occurring. After a second the state should be "completed". The Twilio Console Logs should show all of these state change events in the order they occur. If you are using Ngrok locally, it too should show these state change events (from the webhooks Twilio generates).